# Random product links replaced with Hashtag links

Tags: magento-1.7, product

I'm fairly new with Magento having just started at a new company and have adopted the previous web managers broken database/website.

**Background**: One of the main issues we've been having is that the Dedicated server crashed every time we try run the Catalog Search Index when requested to "Rebuild Catalog product fulltext search index".

**Issue**: But more to the point, the product links from around the site (new and old) are randomly resetting from their product pages to the root url with a hashtag link.

i.e: [www.iwarehouse.co.za/electronics/gaming/gaming-consoles/xbox-360-console-fifa15-bundle/](http://www.iwarehouse.co.za/electronics/gaming/gaming-consoles/xbox-360-console-fifa15-bundle/) changes to [www.iwarehouse.co.za/#](http://www.iwarehouse.co.za/#)

Its also important to mention that we're running Magento 1.7, our DB is about 40GB in size with about 30k products so far.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `core_url_rewrite` table & verify that you have rewrite url there.

Take a backup of your Database, 'Truncate core_url_rewrite' & run `Catalog URL Rewrites` process.

See if its work or not.

Another thing Use `SSH` to build your indexes again, see here [How to index via SSH?](http://adeelishfaq.com/reindex-data-in-magento-by-using-ssh/)